# how to provide --from-file parameter via jenkins openshift build plugin

Tags: openshift, jenkins-pipeline

I want to convert the below openshift command to run from jenkins pipeline by 
openshift build plugin.

```
oc start-build ${appName}-docker --from-file=microservicesdemoapp/target/myapp.jar -n ${project}
```

The problem is that I can't find how to provide the --from-file parameter via the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It would just get passed as an individual quoted argument similar to below:

```
openshift.startBuild("${applicationName}", "--from-dir=.", "--wait=true", "-n 
${projectName}")
```